# Confidence intervals for stratified sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, stratification

Let's suppose that I divided my population $N$ into 3 groups:

$N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$

I used stratified sampling to get samples which are representativie for each group, let's call them

$n_1$,$n_2$ and $n_3$.

The sum, of course, is equal to $n$. Now I want to compute the confidence interval for the mean, sigma unknown. Can I use the well known procedure for each group $n_1$,$n_2$ and $n_3$ to get the range of the unknown mean of, respectively,$N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$  or it's possible only to find the confidence interval respect to $n$, i.e compute a confidence interval to find only the range of the mean of $N$?

Confidence interval is:
$\overline{x} \pm t^{*} \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: To what "well known procedure" do you refer?  What do you mean by "confidence interval for $n$," given that you know the value of $n$ (and it's not even a parameter to be estimated in the first place)?

Comment: I want to find the range in which, with some probability, the mean of my population will be. To do this I use the information of my sample to do inference on all the population. Since my population is stratified, I used stratified sampling. Can I use the formula for each stratified sample? Given that I compute the sample mean for each sub-sample and use the sample sd of each one. I added the formula.

Comment: It depends on how you selected the strata and their sizes.  In no case will simply adding the confidence limits be correct.

Comment: My stratas have different sizes, for example each strata represents a group of bank users. The sum of each strata is my sample. I want to know if it is correct to apply that formula to each strata, using for each one its own mean, sd and numerosity to have a range in which the corresponding mean of the group in population is.

Comment: You seem to have confounded the sizes of the *strata*, which are disjoint subsets of the population about which you wish to make inferences, and the sizes of your *subsamples.*  You need to consider *both* sets of quantities in the calculation.  And now you seem to have changed the question: initially you stated you want to "do inference on all the population" and now you state you want to derive an interval for "the corresponding mean of the group."  Please edit your post so that it expresses one clear question and so that it provides the information needed for its solution.

Comment: That was the explaination of confidence interval that you requested me. My question is just one, can I compute confidence intervals for stratified sample?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not request an explanation of "confidence interval"--there are hundreds of such explanations on this site already.  I'm trying to help you state an answerable question.

Comment: I added details in the question that may help the reader.